# How to you save a string to a table View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is the code:

```
import UIKit

var reminder = [String]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func checkMarkTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        reminder.append(textField.text!)
        textField.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func addReminder(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reminder.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:CoustemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CoustemCell
        cell.tableViewLabel.text = reminder[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

So I when ever you press on the checkMarkTapped it would add whatever is being put in the textField to the table View. But the code that I put in the checkMarkTapped is suppose to work but keeps crashing.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it say when it crash?

Comment: Have you assigned the textfield to the textfield outlet?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var reminder = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tbl_Update: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func checkMarkTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        reminder.append(textField.text!)
        textField.text = ""
        tbl_Update.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func addReminder(sender: AnyObject)
    {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return reminder.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:CoustemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CoustemCell
        cell.tableViewLabel.text = reminder[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Refer link for code if you still have problem with answer   https://github.com/shemona-ios/TableViewUpdateValue.git